# Prolog - Arithmetic mean and merge

Tags: prolog, mean

I have this query in Prolog:

> ?- order([[person1, [7,8,8,9]], [person2, [8,9,8,9]], [person3,
>   [6,7,5,4]]],X).

I need the arithmetic mean of each person and then use mergesort, something like this:

> X=[[person2,[8,9,8,9],8.5],[person1,[7,8,8,9],8],[person3,[6,7,5,4],5.5]].

I know how to get the arithmetic mean for one list, but in this case I will need something recursive, I think.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "mergesort": do you want to just find the means and sort by this mean in decreasing order? Why "mergesort" specifically? Can you use the built-in sort predicates?

Comment: No problem, It is possible to use any sorting method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying a predicate to each member of a list to obtain a new list is what `maplist` is for. For sorting, you can use the built-in `keysort/2`, or, if you have the latest SWI-Prolog version, [`sort/4`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sort/4). However, it would be better if you used pairs (for example) and not just another item in a list (you know the number of "things", after all):

```
person_vals_mean([P, Vs], Mean-[P, Vs]) :-
    numlist_mean(Vs, Mean). % assuming you have defined it elsewhere

order(PVs, Ordered) :-
    maplist(person_vals_mean, PVs, PVMs),
    keysort(PVMs, Ordered_rev),
    reverse(Ordered_rev, Ordered).
```

It might be wise to also get rid of the lists altogether: why `[person, [1,2,3]]` and not `person_vals(person, [1,2,3])`? With this representation, you can rewrite `person_vals_mean/2` as:

```
person_vals_mean(person_vals(P, Vs), Mean-person_vals(P, Vs)) :- ...
```

Or, if you can use `sort/4`, even:

```
person_vals_mean(person_vals(P, Vs), person_vals_mean(P, Vs, M)) :-
    numlist_mean(Vs, M).

order_by_means(PVs, Ordered) :-
    maplist(person_vals_mean, PVs, PVMs),
    sort(3, @>=, PVMs, Ordered).
```

And then:

```
?- order_by_means([person_vals(person1, [7,8,8,9]),
                   person_vals(person2, [8,9,8,9]),
                   person_vals(person3, [6,7,5,4])],
                  Ordered).
Ordered = [person_vals_mean(person2, [8, 9, 8, 9], 8.5),
           person_vals_mean(person1, [7, 8, 8, 9], 8),
           person_vals_mean(person3, [6, 7, 5, 4], 5.5)].
```

As a matter of fact, all sorting built-ins in SWI-Prolog use a merge sort algorithm, but this is implemented in C and really quite irrelevant.